# Wordpress deletes contents of PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website running Wordpress, with a customized theme (that was not developed by me). Yesterday I have attempted a routine modification of a file called `header-home.php`, via the web interface, and unfortunately Wordpress saves the file as blank after I click on "update". And it keeps saving as blank every time I try: now the file is empty and my site is broken! Luckily I have a copy of this file, but I don't see how to restore it.

Is there a workaround for this bug?

Thank you so much. This is quite distressing.

Pierre

PS Wordpress offers to update to 6.1.1 and I do not dare to update, for fear that things will get even worse...

Comment: Use Any FTP Client for file modifications. From the WordPress theme/plugin editor interface sometimes you get issues as you explained. The reason for such behavior could be anything, it can be a typo or logic mistake in code or anything else.

Comment: Ensure you have disk space available there.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'm sorted. I've used an FTP client, to realize that there was no disk space left !! Just deleted one big image and it's all fixed.